# Unable to save map layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

[image]

I don't see the save as layer file option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the **layer** not the **data frame**.

Comment: thanks man always get the data frame and layer confused some time. It worked

Comment: @Lion please don't say thanks in a comment, but accept the answer (because it solved your problem) and upvote it if you think that the answer is well written.

Comment: @Lion don't worry you're definitely not the first and doesn't help that the data frame is called 'Layers' when you start a new map --- DUH!!! Good luck!